# How to Iterate over a list object to insert values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list object queryset, like

```
**class_details**

[<obj1>, <obj2>, <obj3>]
```

SO, Now I want to iterate through the list object to insert values in my dictionary of all list objects,
I tried as follow, but it's replacing each time with old value.
what could be the efficient way, so I can get all list object value in my dicitonary-

Any help would be appricited.

```
for i in class_details:
    class_info = {
        'Sub Type': i.sub_type,
        'Sch Name': i.name,
        'High Amount': i.highestscore,
        'Roll Number': i.subnumber,
    }
return class_info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over `class_details` and replacing `class_info` each time. Note how if you did a print() within in the loop, you would get each class_info output singularly.

In your post you say that you want a dictionary of values that are arrays of all the values; if so, step one, init a resource *outside* of the loop, and then *within* the loop, update it.  In this case, the code works like this

```
#init class_info outside of the loop
class_info = {
        'Sub Type': [],
        'Sch Name': [],
        'High Amount': [],
        'Roll Number': [],
    }
for i in class_details:
    class_info['Sub Type'].append(i.sub_type)
    class_info['Sch Name'].append(i.name)
    class_info['High Amount'].append(i.highestscore)
    class_info['Roll Number'].append(i.subnumber)

return class_info
```